# Sigma algebra examples

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So the definition is:

Let $X$ be a set. A sigma algebra is a collection $\Sigma \subset 2^X$ s.t.

(i) $\emptyset \in \Sigma$

(ii) $E \in \Sigma \implies E^c \in \Sigma$

(iii) $E_1, E_2,... \in \Sigma \implies \bigcup \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i \in \Sigma$

If $X=\{0,1\}$ and $2^X= \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\}$ then can someone give an example of a sigma algebra please. I am having trouble understanding what they can be.

Comment: $2^X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. So is $\{\emptyset, X\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All possible $\sigma$-algebras for your $X$:

- $\{\emptyset, \{0,1\}\}$
- $\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\}$

It is a nice exercise to show that these are all possibilities for a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Comment: OK so pick $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, \{0,1\}\}$, condition 1 holds but I don't understand with condition 2. It would be like $E^c=\{\{0\}, \{1\}\}$ but this is not in $\Sigma$...

Comment: Please help $$$$

Comment: Which $E$ did you choose from the second $\Sigma$?

Comment: The first one...

Comment: But there are only two elements in $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, \{0,1\}\}$, namely $\emptyset$ and $\{0,1\}$. What are the complements of these sets?

Comment: ohhh youre meant to take complement of them separately? $\emptyset ^c=\{0,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}^c=\emptyset$ so $E^c=\{\emptyset, \{0,1\}\}$ right?

Comment: Almost correct. For $E = \emptyset$, you have $E^c = \{0,1\}$ and for $E = \{0,1\}$ you have $E^c = \emptyset$.

Comment: Since $\Sigma$ is a set containing sets, you have to be very careful concerning the notation. Note that in condition 2 you have $E \in \Sigma$ and not $E \subset \Sigma$ -- both statements are drastically different.

Comment: I see but it seems to me that this second condition will always hold... can you give an eg of when it wouldn't please.

Comment: Take any subset of $2^X$ which is not contained in the above list (there are two possibilities).

Comment: take $\Sigma =\{\emptyset, \{0\}\}$, if $E=\emptyset$ then $E^c=\{0\} \in \Sigma$ and if $E=\{0\}$ then $E^c=\emptyset \in \Sigma$. what have I done wrong here since it seems to work...

Comment: You always have to take the complement w.r.t. $X$. Hence $\{0\}^c = \{1\}$ and $\emptyset^c = \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I see thanks. one more thing, in my definition on main post, is it meant to be $\Sigma \subseteq 2^X$ instead of it being strict?

Comment: Yes. Almost always "$\subset$" is meant as "$\subseteq$".

Comment: hello, I also wanted to know, when would the third condition of the definition iii ever not hold? It seems so obvious that it will always be true...

Comment: No, it does not always hold. Take $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $\Sigma = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. This satisfies (i), and (ii), but not (iii).

Comment: I cant see how iii does not hold. Please would you explain.

Comment: because $\{1\} \cup \{2\}=\{1,2\} \notin \Sigma$?

Comment: @snowman: Exactly.